# Styling is not applied on first render but it starts working on refresh and it happens in google chrome only

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome, styled-components

while using reactjs with styled-components i am facing an issue of applying styles, that is, when the component first render, it miss styling but when i refresh the page it apply the css, It only happens in google chrome, i tried it on safari, firefox it work smooth with proper styling.

versions:

- react@16.9.0
- styled-components@^4.4.1
- google-chrome@78.0.3904.97

[screenshots](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b71fa0a03e1371d58218e37ba24af75820191119071539/0c0585)

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the browser console when the styles are not loaded?

Comment: Try Incognito mode, maybe extensions issue.

Comment: @awran5 its working on Incognito mode, may i try with disabling all extenstion?

Comment: @SandeshaJ [ScreenShots][https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b71fa0a03e1371d58218e37ba24af75820191119071539/0c0585]

Comment: @UmairRiaz would go one by one to see which one causing this. Also try to clear browser cache, uncheck "cookies" if you don't want to lose your saved login.

Comment: Solved! Thanks @awran5